# Ca'nt start yandex-tank in OpenSuse

Tags: testing, load, performance-testing, opensuse, yandex-tank

My operating system is OpenSuse 13.2
I installed yandex-tank, cloned repository phantom, and created load.ini
When I run yandex-tank issue is:

13:03:18 WARNING: Lock file present: /var/lock/lunapark_q7wk60a3.lock
13:03:18 WARNING: Failed to load info from lock /var/lock/lunapark_q7wk60a3.lock: No section: 'tank'
13:03:18 INFO: Could not get lock. Will retry in 5 seconds ... (There is lock files)

Prompt people what it lacks.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other instances of Yandex.Tank running on that machine, try removing that file manually.

Comment: I install yandex-tank to ubuntu
And I have other error - http://i.imgur.com/X8uCTtf.jpg